# Shifting Neighbouring Cells to Right in Collection View

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

In tvOS, I have a collection view which is horizontally scrolling. On focusing a cell in collection view I want the focused cell to increase its size and also want the neighbouring cells to slide gently to the right. Have achieved increasing the size but is it feasible to achieve the sliding right of the neighbouring cells as well.

Answer (score 0):

This method works for UITableViews. Hopefully it will work for you too.

Implement `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` to set the sizes for each item. For each item, if it should be in expanded mode, return the larger size here. Otherwise, return the default size.

Then, when the cell is tapped (in the delegate method), do this:

```
collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
```

I can't test it now, but this should animate the change. Let me know if it works (or doesn't).